# Swift 4 Decodable - Dictionary with enum as key

Tags: swift, codable

My data structure has an enum as a key, I would expect the below to decode automatically. Is this a bug or some configuration issue?

```
import Foundation

enum AnEnum: String, Codable {
  case enumValue
}

struct AStruct: Codable {
  let dictionary: [AnEnum: String]
}

let jsonDict = ["dictionary": ["enumValue": "someString"]]
let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDict,     options: .prettyPrinted)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
  try decoder.decode(AStruct.self, from: data)
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

The error I get is this, seems to confuse the dict with an array.

> typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath:
>   [Optional(__lldb_expr_85.AStruct.(CodingKeys in
>   _0E2FD0A9B523101D0DCD67578F72D1DD).dictionary)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead."))

Comment: There's now a discussion on the Swift forum about this here: https://forums.swift.org/t/json-encoding-decoding-weird-encoding-of-dictionary-with-enum-values/12995

And a bug for this issue here: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7788

Comment: I tried to do the same thing but I got the following error "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The problem is that [`Dictionary`'s `Codable` conformance](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Codable.swift#L3368) can currently only properly handle `String` and `Int` keys. For a dictionary with any other `Key` type (where that `Key` is `Encodable`/`Decodable`), it is encoded and decoded with an *unkeyed* container (JSON array) with alternating key values.

Therefore when attempting to decode the JSON:

```
{"dictionary": {"enumValue": "someString"}}
```

into `AStruct`, the value for the `"dictionary"` key is expected to be an array.

So,

```
let jsonDict = ["dictionary": ["enumValue", "someString"]]
```

would work, yielding the JSON:

```
{"dictionary": ["enumValue", "someString"]}
```

which would then be decoded into:

```
AStruct(dictionary: [AnEnum.enumValue: "someString"])
```

However, really I think that `Dictionary`'s `Codable` conformance *should* be able to properly deal with any `CodingKey` conforming type as its `Key` (which `AnEnum` can be) – as it can just encode and decode into a keyed container with that key (feel free to [file a bug](https://bugs.swift.org) requesting for this).

Until implemented (if at all), we could always build a wrapper type to do this:

```
struct CodableDictionary<Key : Hashable, Value : Codable> : Codable where Key : CodingKey {

    let decoded: [Key: Value]

    init(_ decoded: [Key: Value]) {
        self.decoded = decoded
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Key.self)

        decoded = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
            try container.allKeys.lazy.map {
                (key: $0, value: try container.decode(Value.self, forKey: $0))
            }
        )
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {

        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: Key.self)

        for (key, value) in decoded {
            try container.encode(value, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

and then implement like so:

```
enum AnEnum : String, CodingKey {
    case enumValue
}

struct AStruct: Codable {

    let dictionary: [AnEnum: String]

    private enum CodingKeys : CodingKey {
        case dictionary
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        dictionary = try container.decode(CodableDictionary.self, forKey: .dictionary).decoded
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(CodableDictionary(dictionary), forKey: .dictionary)
    }
}
```

(or just have the `dictionary` property of type `CodableDictionary<AnEnum, String>` and use the auto-generated `Codable` conformance – then just speak in terms of `dictionary.decoded`)

Now we can decode the nested JSON object as expected:

```
let data = """
{"dictionary": {"enumValue": "someString"}}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let result = try decoder.decode(AStruct.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}

// AStruct(dictionary: [AnEnum.enumValue: "someString"])
```

---

Although that all being said, it could be argued that all you're achieving with a dictionary with an `enum` as a key is just a `struct` with optional properties (and if you expect a given value to always be there; make it non-optional).

Therefore you may just want your model to look like:

```
struct BStruct : Codable {
    var enumValue: String?
}

struct AStruct: Codable {

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case bStruct = "dictionary"
    }

    let bStruct: BStruct
}
```

Which would work just fine with your current JSON:

```
let data = """
{"dictionary": {"enumValue": "someString"}}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let result = try decoder.decode(AStruct.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}

// AStruct(bStruct: BStruct(enumValue: Optional("someString")))
```

Comment: I don't control the API so can't restructure the data at that point. Implementing as CodableDictionary seems like my best option as the model has a bunch of other fields and (unless I'm missing something?) there's no way to benefit from the auto generated code once I override init(from decoder:). 

A struct with enum keys is similar but the api specifies ordering of those values by key in a separate array of those keys(not my api!). I'll be sure to file a bug report.

Answer (score 6):

In order to solve your problem, you can use one of the two following Playground code snippets.

---

### #1. Using `Decodable`'s `init(from:)` initializer

```
import Foundation

enum AnEnum: String, Codable {
    case enumValue
}

struct AStruct {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case dictionary
    }
    enum EnumKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case enumValue
    }

    let dictionary: [AnEnum: String]
}

extension AStruct: Decodable {

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let dictContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: EnumKeys.self, forKey: .dictionary)

        var dictionary = [AnEnum: String]()
        for enumKey in dictContainer.allKeys {
            guard let anEnum = AnEnum(rawValue: enumKey.rawValue) else {
                let context = DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Could not parse json key to an AnEnum object")
                throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(context)
            }
            let value = try dictContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: enumKey)
            dictionary[anEnum] = value
        }
        self.dictionary = dictionary
    }

}
```

*Usage:*

```
let jsonString = """
{
  "dictionary" : {
    "enumValue" : "someString"
  }
}
"""

let data = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let aStruct = try! decoder.decode(AStruct.self, from: data)
dump(aStruct)

/*
 prints:
 ▿ __lldb_expr_148.AStruct
   ▿ dictionary: 1 key/value pair
     ▿ (2 elements)
       - key: __lldb_expr_148.AnEnum.enumValue
       - value: "someString"
 */
```

---

### #2. Using `KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol`'s `decode(_:forKey:)` method

```
import Foundation

public enum AnEnum: String, Codable {
    case enumValue
}

struct AStruct: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case dictionary
    }

    let dictionary: [AnEnum: String]
}

public extension KeyedDecodingContainer  {

    public func decode(_ type: [AnEnum: String].Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> [AnEnum: String] {
        let stringDictionary = try self.decode([String: String].self, forKey: key)
        var dictionary = [AnEnum: String]()

        for (key, value) in stringDictionary {
            guard let anEnum = AnEnum(rawValue: key) else {
                let context = DecodingError.Context(codingPath: codingPath, debugDescription: "Could not parse json key to an AnEnum object")
                throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(context)
            }
            dictionary[anEnum] = value
        }

        return dictionary
    }

}
```

*Usage:*

```
let jsonString = """
{
  "dictionary" : {
    "enumValue" : "someString"
  }
}
"""

let data = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let aStruct = try! decoder.decode(AStruct.self, from: data)
dump(aStruct)

/*
 prints:
 ▿ __lldb_expr_148.AStruct
   ▿ dictionary: 1 key/value pair
     ▿ (2 elements)
       - key: __lldb_expr_148.AnEnum.enumValue
       - value: "someString"
 */
```

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 5.6 (Xcode 13.3) [SE-0320 CodingKeyRepresentable](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0320-codingkeyrepresentable.md) has been implemented which solves the issue.

It adds implicit support for dictionaries keyed by enums conforming to `RawRepresentable` with `Int` and `String` raw values.

Comment: Excellent answer @vadian - this is the correct answer in 2022.

Answer (score 3):

Swift Proposal [[SE-0320]](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0320-codingkeyrepresentable.md) now allow us to use use a non `String/Int` (e.g. a enum) as key of a dictionary.

To enable that, the type just needs to conform to **`CodingKeyRepresentable`** protocol.

See an example below:

```
enum Device: String, Codable, CodingKeyRepresentable {
   case iphone
   case mac
   case watch
}

var deviceCollection = [Device: [String]]()

// encoding and decoding will work exactly the same as String/Int
let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(deviceCollection)

let content = try JSONDecoder().decode(data, from: [Device: [String]].self)
```

Comment: This was covered in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44725639/20287183) 6 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Following from Imanou's answer, and going super generic. This will convert any RawRepresentable enum keyed dictionary. No further code required in the Decodable items.

```
public extension KeyedDecodingContainer
{
    func decode<K, V, R>(_ type: [K:V].Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> [K:V]
        where K: RawRepresentable, K: Decodable, K.RawValue == R,
              V: Decodable,
              R: Decodable, R: Hashable
    {
        let rawDictionary = try self.decode([R: V].self, forKey: key)
        var dictionary = [K: V]()

        for (key, value) in rawDictionary {
            guard let enumKey = K(rawValue: key) else {
                throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(DecodingError.Context(codingPath: codingPath,
                     debugDescription: "Could not parse json key \(key) to a \(K.self) enum"))
            }
            
            dictionary[enumKey] = value
        }

        return dictionary
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Giles's answer, here is the same idea, but in the other direction, for encoding

```
public extension KeyedEncodingContainer {
    mutating func encode<K, V, R>(_ value: [K: V], forKey key: Key) throws
        where K: RawRepresentable, K: Encodable, K.RawValue == R,
              V: Encodable,
              R: Encodable, R: Hashable {
        try self.encode(
            Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: value.map { ($0.key.rawValue, $0.value) }),
            forKey: key
        )
    }

    mutating func encodeIfPresent<K, V, R>(_ value: [K: V]?, forKey key: Key) throws
        where K: RawRepresentable, K: Encodable, K.RawValue == R,
              V: Encodable,
              R: Encodable, R: Hashable {
        if let value = value {
            try self.encode(value, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```