# How to declare a Swift enum whose rawValue is Int that can be used as key in json map?

Tags: json, swift, enums

Suppose there is a json map whose key is `String` that converted from `Int`, such as `"1"`. How can I declare a Swift enum whose `rawValue` is `Int` to match its key?

In the code listed below, if the key of `map` in `ModelA` is `String`, then the `model` will be deserialized correctly.

But if I replace `String` with `EnumA`, `EnumB`, `EnumC` or `EnumD`, the `model` will be `nil` at last.

```swift
struct ModelA: Codable {
    let pan: String

    let map: [String: ModelB] // Try to replace string with a swift enum.

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case pan, map
    }
}

struct ModelB: Codable {
    let pan: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case pan
    }
}

enum EnumA: Int, Codable {
    case a = 1
    case b = 2
}

enum EnumB: String, Codable {
    case a = "1"
    case b = "2"
}

enum EnumC: Int, Codable {
    case a = 1
    case b = 2

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case a = "1", b = "2"
    }
}

enum EnumD: Int, Codable {
    case a = 1, b = 2

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let status = try? container.decode(String.self)
        switch status {
        case "1":
            self = .a
        case "2":
            self = .b
        default:
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(EnumD.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "??????", underlyingError: nil))
        }
    }
}

extension String {
    func toModel<Model: Decodable>(_ type: Model.Type) -> Model? {
        guard
            let data = data(using: .utf8)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try? decoder.decode(Model.self, from: data)
    }
}

let str2 = """
{"pan": "234", "map":{"1":{"pan": "aaa"}}}
"""

let model = str2.toModel(ModelA.self)
print(model)
```

Comment: you just have to write custom decode/encode methods https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Comment: You are changing the behavior in `ModelA` not the `enum` write the custom decode and encode for `ModelA`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for iOS 15.4+, swift 5.6+ :**

You can use [CodingKeyRepresentable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codingkeyrepresentable)

**Example:**

```
struct ModelA: Codable {
    let pan: String

    let map: [EnumA: ModelB] // Try to replace string with a swift enum.

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case pan, map
    }
}

struct ModelB: Codable {
    let pan: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case pan
    }
}

enum EnumA: Int, Codable, CodingKeyRepresentable {
    case a = 1
    case b = 2
}

extension String {
    func toModel<Model: Decodable>(_ type: Model.Type) -> Model? {
        guard
            let data = data(using: .utf8)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try? decoder.decode(Model.self, from: data)
    }
}

let str2 = """
        {"pan": "234", "map":{"1":{"pan": "aaa"}}}
        """
let model = str2.toModel(ModelA.self)
print(model)
```

[Proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0320-codingkeyrepresentable.md) have accepted

**For swift 5.5 and earlier:**

Dictionary only decoded the `Int` or `String` types. For other Keys it used [UnkeyedDecodingContainer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decoder/2893802-unkeyedcontainer)
You can see source code [Codable.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/release/5.6/stdlib/public/core/Codable.swift#L5615) by swift 5.6

And maybe you can find the solution here [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44725202/swift-4-decodable-dictionary-with-enum-as-key)